# UPDATE MySQL with JQuery sortable new value

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

**Question:** How can I UPDATE my MySQL-database with the new value from a JQuery sortable list?

**This is my code this far:**

```
<?php

echo '
<form action="" method="post"> 
<ul id="sortable">';

$array = str_split("ABCDEFGHI", 3);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  echo '
    <li class="ui-state-default">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>' . $array[$i] . '<input type="hidden" name="pos[]" value="'.$array[$i].'">
    </li>';
}

echo '
</ul><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show order">
</form>

</body>
</html>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['pos'] as $value){
        echo $value;
    }

}

?>
```

**Information:**

`$value` holds the new value from JQuery sortable list that I want to UPDATE my MySQL-database with. But can't be used outside foreach. So how can I do it? I know I can make a variable that holds the SQL-query (in foreach) like this:

```
$query ="UPDATE test SET order='" . $value . "' WHERE id='" . $random_function . "'";
```

But how do I use the variable `$query` to perform the actual SQL-query?

**`$_POST['pos']` array-structure:**

```
Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => DEF [2] => GHI ) Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => DEF [2] => GHI ) Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => DEF [2] => GHI )
```

Comment: what is your $_POST['pos'] structure?

Comment: How do you mean? I think it creates an array with the value.

Comment: that i know it's an array. what is the array structure there? can you add that to the question. use print_r().

Comment: Look at the question again. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: why you are not using mysql_query inside the foreach loop

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't inserted the whole string. Just the last value from JQuery sortable list. If I print the value I've got the whole string, but if I insert it to MySQL-database it just takes the last value. My query is: mysql_query("UPDATE users SET regnr='" . $value . "' WHERE username='" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "'") or die(mysql_error()); Any idea?

Comment: you mean you need only the last value from Array ( [0] => ABC [1] => DEF [2] => GHI ) to be update. here the case is GHI.

Comment: No, I need all values, but it just insert the last one. If I type "echo $value" in the foreach loop I've got all values (like ABCDEFGHI). But if I use $value in the query it just insert one value (GHI). But I want to rearrange with JQuery sortable and insert the new rearranged value. Do you get it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this .

```
$str = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  foreach($_POST['pos'] as $value){
    $str = $str.$value;
  }
 }

$query ="UPDATE test SET order='" . $str . "' WHERE id='" . $random_function . "'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: end($value) replace with end($array). Edited in the answer.

Comment: Still just update the database with the last JQuery sortable value. I don't get any error messages. I rearranged ABCDEFGHI to GHIDEFABC and it just updated with ABC in the database. But if I type echo $value; in the foreach loop it displays all values. :S

Comment: you need to update this in the database. GHIDEFABC or ABCDEFGHI. am i currect?

Comment: Is it so then instead $array[] = $value; use $str = $str.$value; and also replace end($array) with $str.

Comment: Yes! I've got a JQuery sortable list. Variable $value give me a value from the list (ABCDEFGHI). Like list1=ABC, list2=DEF and list3=GHI. With the JQuery sortable list I can rearrange this three values to whatever I like. I want to update the database with the new value in $value. Do you understand? :)

Comment: If I use $str = $str.$value; and insert $str to database I've got: Notice: Undefined variable: str in /path/ on line X. :/

Comment: Declaration on what? Thx for helping me btw! :)

Comment: Sorry, forget `$str = '';` in the code. It's working right now. Thank you Sibiraj PR! :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it like this:

in JavaScript

```
var ids = [];
rows.each(function (index, value)
{
    ids.push($(value).attr("data-item-id"));
});
$.post('/url/to/save/order/, {orderMap:JSON.stringify(ids)}, function() {}, 'json');
```

in PHP:

```
$orderMap = json_decode(stripslashes($this->getPost("orderMap")));
$statements = array();
foreach ($orderMap as $itemId => $position) {
    $statements[] = sprintf("UPDATE `{$tableName}` SET `{$fieldName}`=%d WHERE `{$fieldIdName}`=%d", $position, $itemId);
}
$this->db->executeMultiQuery(implode(";", $statements));
```

Comment: Okey, thanks! :) But how do I use it in my code? How do I use the line $this->db->executeMultiQuery(implode(";", $statements)); in my code? :S Is there any way to just use a regular mysql_query() to insert the value?

Comment: I use class mysqli ($connection is new mysqli()):
if ($connection->multi_query($query)) {
    $results = array();
    $i = 0;
    do {
     if ($result = $connection->store_result()) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $results[$i][] = $row;
      }
      $result->free();
     }
     $i++;
    } while ($connection->next_result());

    return $results;
   }